# File location problems

Tags: php, html, css, location, file-handling

I have a navbar on each page a footer and css etc. I have put a php file 2 folder in so raffles/page/pagetemp.php because this is a template for more files that will be created later and this is for more order so it wont all get cluttered into 1 file.

I used `include '../../navbar.php';` to make it include the navbar into the file as well wich works beautifully, but the problem is now the href on the navbar are all direct links to the file so for example index.php
When I click on the buttons in the pagetemp.php they don't direct me into the main folders index. They try to find a index in the folder I'm in now, same with images.

I cannot start adding ../../ in front of all the links because then the other pages wouldn't work. How can I solve this problem is there for example "host/index.php" so then it would always know to look into the host folder?

```html
<!-- example of a button in the navbar located in the host folder -->
<a href="raffles.php"><p class="button">Raffles</p></a>

<!-- what I am using to include the navbar into the pagetemp.php located in host/raffles/page-->
<?php include '../../navbar.php';?>
```

**I apolagise if this is confusing if you have any questions please comment so I can answer them.**

Comment: Try with these http://yagudaev.com/posts/resolving-php-relative-path-problem/

Comment: This is awesome thank you it works for the include but do you also know how to do this for the images that appear in the navbar? @Nightwhistle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually I use $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/folder/navbar.php');
```

Than simply define the folder structure starting from the root. This way it becomes a relative path and should work on every page you put it

Comment: This is awesome it works like a charm! Is there a way I can also use this on pictures that appear in the navbar and other places?

Comment: If you're using pictures in a html <img> tag you can simply put a / infront of it and it will start in the root as default behavior. So <img src="/test/image.jpg"> Will start in the root and than open folder 'test' to look for the image